# Inject CSS Modules to Per-Component Style Elements (for portability to shadow root)

Tags: reactjs, webpack, shadow-dom, webpack-style-loader, react-css-modules

### TL:DR

How can I get CSS of React components to work inside of a shadow root, while keeping the
encapsulation benefits of CSS Modules class? I'd like to insert per-component `<style>` elements instead of inside of `<head>` or another arbitrary element.

### What I have

I'm currently using CSS Modules in React with a custom Webpack script; `[style-loader, css-loader, sass-loader]` in the traditional way. The resulting compiled CSS is injected as `<style>` tags in `head`.

```
    // MyComponent.jsx
    import React from 'react';
    import styles from './MyComponent.scss';

    export const MyComponent = () => {
      return <div className={styles.container}>Hello!</div>
    }

    // MyComponent.scss
    .container {
      background: purple;
    }
```

#### result

```
    <!-- rendered page -->
    <head>
      ...
      <style>.myComponent__container__hash123 { background: purple }</style>
    </head>
    <body>
      ...
      <div class="myComponent__container__hash123">Hello!</div>
    </body>
```

### What I want

For use inside of a shadow root, I would like to instead inject each component's compiled CSS into a `<style>` tag on its root.

```
    <!-- rendered page -->
    <head>
      ...
    </head>
    <body>
      ...
      <div>
        #shadow-root
          <div class="myComponent__container__hash123">Hello!</div>
          <style>.myComponent__container__hash123 { background: purple }</style>
        #end shadow-root
      </div>
    </body>
```

### What I tried

#### 1. insert

This will not work for component libraries which compile themselves, where I cannot know the end consumer in advance.

#### 2. `to-string-loader`

https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-to-string-loader

When combined with `style-loader`, the result is classnames aren't resolved (e.g. `styles.container === undefined`).

---

Ideally I would have `import styles from './MyComponent'` contain the compiled CSS string in addition to classname mapping - however this is not supported as per [style-loader docs](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/style-loader)

Comment: Have you checked out [react-shade](https://github.com/treshugart/react-shade)?

Comment: can you tell me why do you need this ?

Comment: @AmirRezvani I'm looking to convert existing React components using CSS Modules for styling to run inside shadowRoots. A straightforward solution would be to have each component come with a self-contained style element.

Comment: @RossAllen thank you - I'm familiar with react-shade, however AFAIK it requires a rewrite of styling from e.g. CSS Modules (using SCSS in my case) to Styled Components or JS object-based styles.

Answer (score 0):

Two years too late, but:

I'm not quite sure if this is what you want, but in React you can add style directly into JSX like this:

```
  <style>
    {`
      body {
        font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        background-color: #151515;
        color: white;
      }
    `}
  </style>
```

or using your example:

```
<style>
    {`
      .myComponent__container__hash123 { 
        background: purple;
      }
    `}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Webpack "style-loader" plugin with `insert` parameter.

```
          {
            loader: "style-loader",
            options: {
              injectType: "lazyStyleTag",
              insert: function insertIntoTarget(element, options) {
                var parent = options.target || document.head;
                parent.appendChild(element);
              },
            },
          },
```

Refer to [this](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/style-loader/#custom-elements-shadow-dom) for more details.